# How to get Session ID? UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a small problem: I don’t know how to get the session id from my found sessions.

More details: I’m creating a multiplayer game, and hosting one game from my PC. From another PC in the LAN, I try to find my Host. I do it, but I get some count(4-5pcs) of sessions with some ID. And I want to identify my game.

For example, while finding sessions I get the:

```
Session - id:1100
Session - id:1101
Session - id:1102
```

And I try to find a way ho to identify my Host session. I want to output to my host its ID. For example, see at the top-left corner ‘`id:1101`’. But I can’t find a way to output this number. I tried a lot of functions, and a lot of methods, but nothing happened, I got another number or some trash.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do exactly. So, you have some clients linked to each other in a multiplayer session with a listen server, because otherwise the host would be dedicated server. Now what do you want to know? Who the host is? How to print a number on screen? Could you give a little more info on what exactly your original problem is?

Comment: I don't know how to identify my game among other games in the online environment.@MaxPlay

Comment: You mean like in a lobby? Or when clients are connected to each other in an online session?

Comment: @MaxPlay I mean like a lobby